# Iterate a TreeSet in html:option

Tags: java, struts

There is a situation where i need to Iterate a `TreeSet` in order to populate a drop down using `html:option` as below,

```
<html:select id="schoolLevel" name="schoolLevel">
   <html:option value="">ALL</html:option>
   <html:options property="schoolLevel" />
</html:select>
```

Due to the current design of the code, i need to do this as TreeSet instead of chaging it to list of a map. Is it possible please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for the [optionsCollection tag](http://struts.apache.org/release/1.3.x/struts-taglib/tagreference.html#html%3aoptionsCollection):

> Renders a set of HTML `<option>` elements, representing possible choices for a `<select>` element. This tag can be used multiple times within a single `<html:select>` element, either in conjunction with or instead of one or more  or `<html:options>` elements.
>
> This tag operates on a collection of beans, where each bean has a label property and a value property. The actual names of these properties can be configured using the label and value attributes of this tag.